# Prepend "chapter" and "appendix" only for non-starred commands

Tags: sectioning, koma-script

I am using a KOMA Script class, and I want to prepend the words "Chapter" and "Appendix" to chapter headings, but only if the chapter was created using a non-starred command (i.e., it has no number/letter).
The command `\chapapp` prints the correct word "Chapter" or "Appendix", but it does it every time, even for starred commands.
My solution uses `etoolbox`'s `\ifstrempty` command to check whether the chapter number is empty, but I wonder if there is a more standard way to do it.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand*\chapterlinesformat[3]{%
    \ifstrempty{#2}{}{\chapapp} #2 #3
}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage\tableofcontents
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}


\chapter*{Publications}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Publications}

\chapter{Introduction}

\appendix

\chapter{Attachments}

\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW: KOMA-Script has a build in command `\IfArgIsEmpty`. However esdd's solution is better.

Answer (score 2):

Redefine `\chapterformat`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}% TOCentry in TOC

\renewcommand\chapterformat{\chapapp~\thechapter\autodot\enskip}% prefix for numbered chapters

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Publications}
\chapter{Introduction}

\appendix
\chapter{Attachments}
\end{document}
```

or if there should be no head entry for the unnumbered chapter »Publications«:

```
\documentclass[headings=optiontoheadandtoc]{scrbook}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}% TOCentry in TOC

\renewcommand\chapterformat{\chapapp~\thechapter\autodot\enskip}% prefix for numbered chapters

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap[head={}]{Publications}
\chapter{Introduction}

\appendix
\chapter{Attachments}
\end{document}
```

---

**Update** regarding a comment:

If »Chapter«/»Appendix« should be typeseted together with the chapter title and not the chapter number,  you can use `\IfArgIsEmpty` in the redefinition of `\chapterlinesformat` (as suggested by @Schweinebacke in a comment):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}% TOCentry in TOC

\let\originalchapterlinesformat\chapterlinesformat
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{chapter}
    {\originalchapterlinesformat{#1}{#2}{\IfArgIsEmpty{#2}{}{\chapapp\enskip}#3}}
    {\originalchapterlinesformat{#1}{#2}{#3}}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Publications}
\chapter{Introduction}

\appendix
\chapter{Attachments}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\setuptoc{toc}{totoc}% TOCentry in TOC

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chapterlinesformat}[3]{%
\ifstr{#1}{chapter}
  {\@hangfrom{#2}{\IfArgIsEmpty{#2}{}{\chapapp\enskip}#3}}
  {\@hangfrom{#2}{#3}}% original definition
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Publications}
\chapter{Introduction}

\appendix
\chapter{Attachments}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but it typeset "Chapter" and the chapter number together, separate from the chapter's title. I guess my MWE was too minimal, because I actually wanted to do the opposite: typeset "Chapter" and the chapter title, plus the chapter number somewhere else.

Comment: See my updated answer. @Schweinebacke Thanks, you are right , it should be »Publications«.